# How to do nested subsetting in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, subset

In my `DATA` below, I'm trying to `filter` the `District`s that have `Status` that includes both `Monitor` and `Never` and have a `No` `Answer`.

Then, in each of those `District`s, I only want to `filter` the rows where `Status` is `Monitor` or `Never` and `Answer` is `No`.

Desired output should be only the 1st, the 3rd, the 10th, and the last row (*see below*). Is this possible?

I tried the following (without success):

```
library(dplyr)
  group_by(DATA, District) %>% 
  filter(Status %in% c("Monitor","Never")  & Answer == "No") %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
DATA <- read.table(h=T, text="
District  Status   Answer
A         Monitor  No    #--> Filter this row
A         Never    Yes
A         Never    No    #--> Filter this row
A         Ever     No
B         Never    Yes
B         Never    No
B         Never    No
C         Former   No
C         Never    No
D         Never    No   #--> Filter this row
D         Monitor  Yes
D         Monitor  No   #--> Filter this row
")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For *"includes both Monitor and Never"*, we need to use `all(.)` first, then we can continue with the rest of your filter.

```r
group_by(DATA, District) %>%
  filter(
    all(c("Monitor","Never") %in% Status),
    Status %in% c("Monitor", "Never"),
    Answer == "No"
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   District Status  Answer
#   <chr>    <chr>   <chr> 
# 1 A        Monitor No    
# 2 A        Never   No    
# 3 D        Never   No    
# 4 D        Monitor No
```